How does persistent damage work with hardness?
Our group came across animated statues during our recent game, and one of the spells our wizard considered casting was dehydrate, which does 1d6 persistent fire damage. But how does that work with the hardness 6? Will it do any damage at all?

The Statue will not take any damage.
The rules say

Each time an item takes damage, reduce any damage the item takes by its Hardness. The rest of the damage reduces the item's Hit Points.

As persistent damage is a type of damage, it would be reduced by Hardness just like any other damage would. With hardness 6, the Animated Statue would never take damage from the spell.

That's what I thought... Thanks!

It's also worth questioning whether dehydrating a statue would have been effective anyway. I don't recall if Pathfinder 2e retained its predecessor's rules regarding Hardness, but historically, actions that would not be affected by Hardness (setting fire to wooden doors, for instance) could bypass some or all of the Hardness. In this case, the composition of the statue might matter.
